# Is it possible to make anchor tag <a> without href attr look like with href attr?

Tags: css

I've made dropdown using angular-ui-bootstrap

public/partials/partial2.html

```
<ul ...
  <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
    <a href="admin/partial2" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle> brand list </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li>.....


</ul>
```

obviously href="admin/partial2" route(by angular-route) to same partial page( so same entire page ) and do nothing

but I need hand emoticon when user put mouse-over the anchor

Can I have this effect without specifying "href" attribute?

Comment: `a { cursor: pointer; }` may help?

Comment: What exactly are you asking. Its not clear to me from your question

Comment: This is not an angular, not an html5, not a Bootstrap, but a CSS question.

Comment: If the element doesn't have a `href` attribute/property, why are you using an `<a>` element in the first place? Why not just style a `<span>` (or other element)?

Comment: perhaps, he needs <a> to get the pointer set :D

Comment: Alan, it would be great if you could accept one of the answers.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am very new to CSS ( frankly, I only use bootstrap.css and haven't modify any of styles),  and I've found that the dropdown toggle anchor of angular-ui-bootstrap doesn't need href-care....... Actually any href attribute ok and I could just use href="",  no need to modify style.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use css for that, create a rule for your anchor class (dropdown-toggle) in this case as follows:

```
.dropdown-toggle:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<a>` without `href`, but it's just like a spam inside your script.
For example, you have a text inside the `div` or, say, `span`, as in:

```
<span>Sitemap</span>
```

or, you have `<ul> <li>` in your dropdown menu, then you can **add NEW Selector** in your stylesheet(or CSS).
for example:

```
.mymenu li {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

From the code, I can explain that, you just need `cursor:pointer`, to make it happen. that's all.

if you set the cursor inside `li`, all `li`'s will have that pointer.
to make it specific, I mean, if you need the pointer for only one scope, say, menu or dropdown menu where `li` or `ul` is used, you can add new selector then.